# Video Games on Linux

Tags: games

What are the main reasons that video games aren't developed for Linux. I get that there are multiple distributions, that use different kernel versions. But there has to be ways. I never understood why it's never a main target for big titles.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jorge, Just to let you know how I feel about that in case it's food for thought. There's hundreds of forums out there. I like this one because it's part of stackEx, which I like because I try to keep my online accounts as few as possible, and it lets me be part of a few forums under one name. I understand there are ground rules, but I disagree that one question is better places on UbuntuForums vs AskUbuntu. If anything, this site should aim to answer more questions than other Forums do to be more productive in more areas.

Comment: Thanks to tags, people can easily categorize their threads. Perhaps a solution would be to include a tag like "open-ended" or "curiosity" as opposed to just telling people they need to go elsewhere.

Comment: We don't do open ended or curiosity here, this is a site for technical Q+A please see the FAQ: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video games are not developed due to the lack of market share. A majority of users are on OS X or Windows systems. The kernel version has nothing to do with it as it is largely the same system after a kernel update. Windows runs has the NT kernel which has different versions, yet it still can run the same games on different versions.

Now that Linux is popularizing games are being made for it. Steam is reportedly coming to Linux, which will probably increase the amount of games developed for the platform.

Answer (score 2):

Very few Linux users + companies need to spend some time and money to make a crossplatform game => it is not profitable.
Also, companies need to test their games on every more or less popular distribution (and several versions of each distro), regardless of the fact that usually different distributions are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
The reason is mentioned cost. However some independent studios work on it, and lately EA decided to start creating games for Linux also, what is a huge step forward for us. For example one of my favourites games ever - [Penumbra](http://www.penumbragame.com/buy.php)  is also developed for Linux.

On the other hand I am working with few of my friends on a two (open source) full free games by default for Ubuntu only. Point&Click and 3rd person Shooter/Adventure game. However, as I do other things for living the work progress is slow. Programming (with Blender or Panda3D) is a piece of cake, creating, characters etc. is much harder as it requires a lot of time and effort.
I think the main problem with games for Linux is that Linux community creates mostly applications which are really necessary, and games, are not. What the Community needs in my opinion is a well organized people who will create games for Linux. Just like Canonical creates Ubuntu, Oracle makes Virtual box, Libre Office foundation and so on.